# How to redirect .htaccess to two MVC trees

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

What I have tried to achieve with apache mod rewrite is the following:

1. *When I access localhost/system/this/is/a/test/, the .htaccess mod rewrite should redirect to my index.php*
2. *When I access localhost/system/api/this/is/a/test/, the .htaccess mod rewrite should redirect to my api.php*

I have been trying this for several hours, but i can not seem to get it working the way that I would like. Currently all access is still pointing to index, and no matter what I try I can not seem to get the .htaccess to point to both the api and the index depending on the URL.

The following is my current .htaccess file:

```
ExpiresActive On

ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2 weeks"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 2 weeks"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2 weeks"

AddType application/x-httpd-php .xml

Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes 

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /system/

# file access exclusions
RewriteRule ^(?!sitemap\.xml$).(.*)\.xml$ [R=404,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.log$ [R=404,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.txt$ [R=404,L]

# Rewrite the request to API
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^api/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php/$1 [L]

# Rewrite the request to index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Can any of you explain to me what I am doing wrong? That would be a great help and greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your rules with this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /system/

# file access exclusions
RewriteRule ^(?!sitemap\.xml$).(.*)\.xml$ [R=404,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(txt|log)$ - [R=404,L]

# Rewrite the request to API
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ api.php/$1 [L]

# Rewrite the request to index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```